# Amazon Linux 2023 に zabbix-server-mysql と zabbix-agent がインストールできません

Tags: amazon-linux, zabbix

#### 前提条件

・最終目的：AWS上にZabbixを構築
・使用OS：Amazon Linux 2023
・使用データベース：RDSのMySQL
・zabbixバージョン：6.4
・EC2とRDSは構築済み。zabbixパッケージインストールの時にエラー発生。

#### 本題

AWS上にZabbixを構築するためにzabbix-server-mysql、zabbix-web-mysql、zabbix-apache-conf、zabbix-sql-scripts、zabbix-selinux-policy、zabbix-agentをインストールしようしました。
ですが、その内のzabbix-server-mysql、zabbix-agentがインストールできません。

エラーメッセージを見て、依存性の問題であると判断した私はlibldap.so.2()(64bit)と libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit)を外部サイトからrpmインストールしようとしたものの、そこでも依存性の問題が発生しうまくいきませんでした。

エラーを解消しようと奮闘しているのですが、解決せず困り果てています。アドバイスをいただけると幸いです。

#### 参考にしたサイト

・ec2とRDSの構築時に参考にした。
https://infrastructure-engineer.com/tcpip-advanced-0008/
https://infrastructure-engineer.com/tcpip-advanced-0009/

・Zabbix構築時に参考にしている。
https://www.tcdigital.jp/dev_blog/infrastructure/al2023%E3%81%ABzabbix6-0rds%E3%81%A7ha%E6%A7%8B%E6%88%90%E3%81%AB%E6%8C%91%E6%88%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F/

#### エラー発生時のログ

```
[root@ec2-user]# dnf install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql                                                                              zabbix-apache-conf zabbix-sql-scripts zabbix-selinux-policy zabbix-agent
Amazon Linux 2023 repository                     52 MB/s |  24 MB     00:00
Amazon Linux 2023 Kernel Livepatch repository   881 kB/s | 165 kB     00:00
Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64             115 kB/s | 192 kB     00:01
Zabbix Official Repository non-supported - x86_ 990  B/s | 1.1 kB     00:01
Package zabbix-web-mysql-6.4.11-release1.el9.noarch is already installed.
Package zabbix-apache-conf-6.4.11-release1.el9.noarch is already installed.
Package zabbix-sql-scripts-6.4.11-release1.el9.noarch is already installed.
Package zabbix-selinux-policy-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64 is already installed.
Error:
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.0-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.1-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.10-                                                                             release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.11-                                                                             release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-r                                                                             elease2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.3-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.4-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.5-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.6-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.7-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.8-r                                                                             elease2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.9-r                                                                             elease1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server                                                                             -mysql-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.0-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.1-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.10-release                                                                             1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.11-release                                                                             1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release2                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.3-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.4-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.5-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.6-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.7-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.8-release2                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.9-release1                                                                             .el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-                                                                             6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Comment: "amazon linux 2023 zabbix agent install" で検索するといくつか事例が出てきます。 [Amazon Linux2023にzabbixエージェントインストール](https://www.ecomottblog.com/?p=11290), [AL2023にzabbix6.0+RDSでHA構成に挑戦してみた](https://www.tcdigital.jp/dev_blog/infrastructure/al2023%E3%81%ABzabbix6-0rds%E3%81%A7ha%E6%A7%8B%E6%88%90%E3%81%AB%E6%8C%91%E6%88%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
その事例も試したのですが、うまくいきませんでした。
また都合上、zabbixのバージョンは6.4ですと幸いです。