# Amazon Linux2023を使ってAWS上にZabbix6.4（最新版）を構築することは可能なのでしょうか。

Tags: amazon-linux, zabbix

◎前提条件
・最終目的：AWS上にZabbixを構築
・使用OS：Amazon Linux 2023
・使用データベース：RDSのMySQL
・zabbixバージョン：6.4
・EC2とRDSは構築済み。zabbixパッケージインストールの時にエラー発生。

◎本題
Amazon Linux2023を使ってZabbix6.4（最新版）を構築することは可能なのでしょうか。

現在、AWS上にZabbixを構築しようとしています。
Zabbixの公式サイトの手順通り、zabbix-server-mysql、zabbix-web-mysql、zabbix-apache-conf、zabbix-sql-scripts、zabbix-selinux-policy、zabbix-agentをインストールしようとしました。しかし、それらの内、zabbix-server-mysqlとzabbix-agentが依存性の関係なのかインストールすることができません。

インストールを求められているであろうlibldap.so.2()(64bit)とlibldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit)を外部サイトからRPMインストールしようとしたのですが上手くいきません。
外部サイトのリンク：
https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit)

利用したrpmファイル：https://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/o/openldap-2.6.7-1.fc40.x86_64.rpm

そもそも、Amazon Linux2023ではZabbix6.4を構築できないのではとすら思ってしまっています。その点についてもご回答いただきたいです。

この条件で構築した経験のある方に関しては手順なども教えていただくととても助かります。もちろん、構築したことのない方のご回答も大歓迎です！

自分がやれるだけのことをやっても上手くいかなかったので、困り果てています
ご回答いただけるととてもうれしいです！！

※Zabbix公式サポートとベーシックサポート以上の契約はしていません。

◎エラーログ

```
[root@ec2-user]# dnf install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql zabbix-apache-conf zabbix-sql-scripts zabbix-selinux-policy zabbix-agent zabbix-get zabbix-web-japanese
Last metadata expiration check: 0:09:34 ago on Thu Feb 22 03:06:55 2024.
Error:
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-server-mysql-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.0-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.1-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.10-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.11-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.2-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.3-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.4-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.5-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.6-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.7-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.8-release2.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides liblber.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2()(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
  - nothing provides libldap.so.2(OPENLDAP_2.200)(64bit) needed by zabbix-agent-6.4.9-release1.el9.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Comment: ひとつ前のご質問 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/98676/19110 との差分は何でしょうか？　単なる情報追加であれば、前の質問の質問文を編集して追記するようにしてみてください。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
差分は特にないです。質問の仕方を変えた方が回答が集まりやすいのではないかと思い、追加で質問を作りました。

Comment: なるほど。スタック・オーバーフローでは、Q&A の質を高めるため、重複した質問を[禁止しています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)。もし次そのようなことをなさりたくなったら、新しく投稿する代わりに元の質問文を編集するようにしてみてください。質問が並んでいるホームのフィードは最終更新が新しい順番で並ぶので編集でも先頭に並びます。今回は新しい方の質問にひとつ回答がついて、古い方の質問は動きなしという状態なので、古い方の質問をクローズしておきますね。引き続きよろしくお願いします 

Comment: 大切なルールを教えてくださり、ありがとうございます。
お手数をかけてしまい申し訳ありません。今後気を付けます。

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Linux 2023 向けのパッケージも用意されているようですが、「ダウンロードにはベーシックサポート以上の契約登録が必要です」との事です。

https://enterprise.zabbix.co.jp/update/18310

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
Amazon Linux2023でZabbix6.4を構築するのは難しいですかね、、、。
自分も必死にAmazon Linux2023でZabbix6.4を構築する記事を探したのですが、見つかりませんでした。
いっそのこと、ディストリビューションをAmazon Linux2023以外のものにした方が良いのかと思ってしまいました、、、。redhatとかに。

Comment: パッケージのコンフリクトを解決するのは現実的ではないので、正攻法としては「サポート契約を受けてAL 2023 のパッケージを入手」「別のディストリビューションを使用する」になると思います。

Comment: ご教授いただいた手段も試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

可能かどうか、で言えば最悪ソースからビルド(マニュアルにも手順が書いてある)すればよっぽどのことがない限り動くでしょうから可能です。

質問の問題を解決できるか、はどのリポジトリを使ったとか｢外部サイト」とはどこかとか重要なポイントが書かれてないので具体的な回答は難しいと思います。そもそも元の環境の問題(非公式のリポジトリ/パッケージを多用してるとか)の可能性も多いにあります。

RPMで簡単にインストールする方法があるかは経験者の回答を待つしかありません。

とにかくZabbixを運用するのが目的なら、(サーバに関しては)パッケージが提供されてるディストリビューションに変えるなり公式のクラウドイメージを使うなりもっと適した方法があるので、目的と手段(それにかけられるコストも含めて)から見直した方がいいようにも思います。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
ご指摘いただいた点を踏まえて編集しました。追加で至らない点がありましたらご指摘いただけると幸いです。